# Rails nested singleton routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-routes

I have a basic User class, and each user has a number of has_one associations with other objects (account, profile, etc).  I have my routes nested as such:

```
resources :users do
  resource :account
  resource :profile
end
```

And that gives me the appropriate routes:

```
        user_profile POST   /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#create
    new_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profile/new(.:format)  profiles#new
   edit_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profile/edit(.:format) profiles#edit
                     GET    /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#show
                     PATCH  /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#update
                     PUT    /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#update
                     DELETE /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#destroy
```

But I want the logged-in user to be able to access their owned objects via URLs like this:

```
/settings/profile
/settings/account
...etc
```

How do I need to set up my routes for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code in your `routes.rb`:

```
resources :users
resource :account, path: 'settings/account'
resource :profile, path: 'settings/profile'
```